# Responsive UI-grid isn't working

Tags: angular-ui-grid

How to make Ui grid Responsive?? kindly help?

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
</div>
</div>
```

correct plz?

Answer (score 0):

In general ui-grid won't do responsive - the nature of it's rendering cycle is that it needs to know how big it is going to be.  Having said that, the auto-resize plugin can do a lot of what you might want, or alternatively if your web-page has knowledge of when the size changed (perhaps you already have an event being triggered) then you could call the `handleResize` method whenever the size changes.